# pyautogui to locate certain text in a dropdown menu

Tags: python, pyautogui

Just discovered the pyautogui function, and its an amazing function

everything works great when i use the x and y coordinates , so i am using x and y coordinates to click on the drop down menu and this menu contains round about 40 options like this :

Alex Lategun 205 north ave
sergy shimer 22 xyz ave
Joe Astpher  11 fifth block
:
:
:
:
:::::::

now if i wanted to select only the field with Joe Astpher  how do i do that so that it selects the required option with lightning fast speed ?

the reason i cant use the x and y coordinates in selecting the options is because the dropdown menu contains the scroll bar and most of the option are hidden 
so what are the possible options for me to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you seen https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html?highlight=scroll#mouse-scrolling

Comment: Hi Justin , yes i have seen the docs , but the scroll function may not be very suitable in this particular situation

Answer (score 1):

If only one option begins with 'j', you can do this for pyautogui to travel to that specific button:

```
pyautogui.typewrite('j')
```

If more than one option begins with 'j', you can count how many times you would need to press 'j' on the keyboard to get there and add that amount of `pyautogui.typewrite('j')` to your script.

Then, make it press it:

```
pyautogui.typewrite('enter')
```